# Is Google Analytics for Mobile available for Windows Mobile / Compact Framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, google-analytics

Recently Google introduced an SDK for application usage tracking on mobile devices ([Google Analytics for Mobile Apps](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/mobileAppsTracking.html)). Unfortunately, it seems that it only supports IPhone and Android devices.

Do you have any idea if this framework can somehow be used from Windows Mobile / Compact Framework applications or if Google is planning to release an SDK for WM?

BTW, I don't mean a WM application for browsing through GA server reports, but an SDK for tracking your mobile app's usage. I'm also not working with mobile website tracking, but with monitoring applications running on Windows Mobile (on Compact Framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at it further it seems that there is no Windows Mobile counterpart of the Android/iPhone package.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's a server-side counterpart to the js-based package you mentioned. It's in beta; you can get it from Google [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/googleanalyticsformobile.zip).

The specific aim of that Project is to allow tracking/data collection on traffic to mobile websites from mobile devices that don't support javascript; As far as i am aware, it provides data collection/analytics for mobile sites that use any of these server-side languages: JSP, PHP, .Net, or Perl.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is tracking usage of a mobile device application, not mobile website. I updated the question to make it more clear.